# Unity MemoryError?

Tags: c#, memory, unity-game-engine, unityscript

After some changes in my code a weird error occured and that's what it says:

```
m_UniqueThreadAllocator->GetAllocatedMemorySize() == 0
```

It seems to appear every second or even more often. What I want to ask you for is the explaination of this kind of bug/error. When usually this happens or what kind of activity can results in this. If needed I will provide you with the code, but I am not sure if this would changed anything. What's more, everything is going fine, no other bugs, gameplay is smooth. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at a [log paste from a similar incident](http://pastebin.com/88aWtYAY) (CTRL+F for your error), it would appear like your system ran out of memory which is why the editor's memory allocations failed. There's probably a memory leak somewhere. Try profiling the editor.